# Feature Extraction Step Taking Too Long

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, signal-processing, octave

I've put together a machine learning routine in Octave which looks as follows:

1. Features are extracted from sound files
2. Features are scaled and normalized
3. SVM classifier is trained
4. Classification is performed

The problem I'm having is that steps 2,3 and 4 take in the range of a couple of seconds to complete for the entire database. Step 1 however, takes about 1 second **per file**, which is excessive.

The reason it's taking so long is - for the most part - because I'm performing multiple exponential fits per file using `leasqr`.

Since I have about 1500 sound files per class and 3 or more classes, it starts adding up. I want to expand to 15,000 files and with the current speed of feature extraction that would not be feasible.

The reason I have to deal with the feature extraction step over and over again is because I've been using it to tweak my classifier performance. E.g. by changing the range over which the exponential fits are performed.

My question is as follows. I have no experience with running laborious processes externally, but would that be a viable solution? If so, what would be good/standard practice for a situation like this? If not, what would be good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your process is highly independent (extraction of features from one file is not dependent in any way on results of extraction of others) the most logical way of dealing with this problem is parallelization. You can run this process on many threads/cores/processors/computers/clusters in the same time, making the whole process as fast as you wish, assuming that you have access to enough computational power. If you are a researcher that with great probability you have access to some computational clusters at your University/Research facility/Company. Otherwise you can always buy access to such resources, for example at Amazon EC2 (however I am sure that you can find cheaper and better clusters).

But it seems, that a **better** (in sense of both price and results) would be to leave Octave behind, as it is **incredibly slow** and perform your preprocessing using efficient languages like c++. If this is not sufficient (and I am quite sure, it will speed things up at least of row of magnitude), then think about parallelization.

In general Matlab/Octave are analysis tools, something that should be used for the research, not for actual computations. Once efficiency is concerned, it is time to do "actual programming".

Comment: Another possibility may simply be the overall algorithm chosen is a poor one, that needs to be rethought. While leasqr may be as fast as it is going to get, perhaps all of these exponential fits need not be done at all, or other algorithms, like a partitioned (or separable) nonlinear least squares may be right. Or maybe the multitude of exponential fits themselves may simply be a bad idea. I have often found that a slow piece of code may be sped up by a huge amount just by an intelligent rethinking of the algorithm.